# How to parse a date string including Μαϊ (greek May) in Java

Tags: java, date, date-parsing

I cannot parse strings that contain dates, that include the short version of the month May in Greek (*Μαϊ*, which is in short for *Μαΐου* - note on the ϊ-ΐ difference).

For example:

```
25 Μαϊ 1989
24 Μαΐ 1967
```

won't parse, if I use the following formats:

```
"d MMM yyyy"
"dd MMM yyyy"
```

through the following code:

```
String dateString = "24 Μαΐ 1967"; // just an example of an input String
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(someFormat);
format.parse(dateString);
```

EDIT: The values I am trying to parse are strings stored in sqlite3 database in Android. In particular it's Contact Birthdays . Although Android dependant, I'll share the code for any insight:

```
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
while(cur.moveToNext()){
   String birthdayString = cur.getString(INDEX_OF_BIRTHDAY);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [constructor with `locale` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale))?

Comment: Are you reading the value of `dateString` from a `Stream` -- or where does it come from?

Comment: @lukaslew Yup, I have tried that. The locale is greek so I tried using new Locale("el") or new Locale("el","GR"), but still nothing.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I am using the code on Android, and that String is a date taken from the birthday database of the device

Comment: How are you reading the value -- are you explicitly specifying a charset encoding?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I am not specifying any charset.

Comment: Does it work if you execute it as a standalone test with code from an answer below?

Comment: careful how you copy and paste the `String dateString = "24 Μαΐ 1967";` I was getting a `ParseException` until I copied the string from @FranzBecker's answer

Comment: Could you edit the post to include the code that reads the value as it seems to play a role here.

Comment: @MickMnemonic It is Android specific I think, but I posted the code anyway. Check the edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are correct, such as [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31973773/642706) by Franz Becker. But they use the old java.util.Date & java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes.

## java.time

Here is similar code but using the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) packages in Java 8 and later.

### Parsing String

The Question provided two example input strings. Notice the different [diacritical signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic). The first one works, but the second one fails. I have no explanation, as I don’t know that language… "It's all Greek to me". ;-)

```
String input1 = "25 Μαϊ 1989";
String input2 = "24 Μαΐ 1967"; // Different diacritical over the "i".
```

Fetch a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) instance using the static method [`Locale.forLanguageTag`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag-java.lang.String-), new in Java 7. Specify an [ISO 639](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) language code (via [IETF BCP 47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCP_47)) for [Modern Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Greek) language.

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("el");
```

Specify the exact pattern we expect.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM yyyy" ).withLocale( locale );
```

Parse using the recommended [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery-) method that takes a method reference ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)), `LocalDate :: from`, in the new Java 8 Lambda syntax.

```
LocalDate localDate1 = formatter.parse( input1, LocalDate :: from );
LocalDate localDate2 = formatter.parse( input2, LocalDate :: from );  // Fails… Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '24 Μαΐ 1967' could not be parsed at index 3.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "localDate1 = " + localDate1 );
```

When run.

```
localDate1 = 1989-05-25
```

### Generating String

Going the other way, to generate a String representation of a LocalDate, let java.time do the work of determining a localized format. Using automated localization may be easier and more flexible that hard-coding a specific format.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput =  DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale );
String output = formatterOutput.format( localDate1 );

System.out.println( "output = " + output );  // output = 25 Μαϊ 1989
```

## Full Month Name

That second input string with a different diacritical seems to be an inappropriate abbreviation of the full month name `Μαΐου`. Using that full month name with another formatter (four `M` pattern characters) does successfully parse. Again, I do not know Modern Greek, so this explanation is just a guess on the part of me and the people commenting on this Answer.

This example code demonstrates the successful parsing of `input3`.

```
String input1 = "25 Μαϊ 1989";
String input2 = "24 Μαΐ 1967";  // Different diacritical over the "i". Incorrect abbreviation of full month name?
String input3 = "23 Μαΐου 1978";  // Full month name with different diacritical.

Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag( "el" );
DateTimeFormatter formatterShort = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM yyyy" ).withLocale( locale );
DateTimeFormatter formatterFull = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMMM yyyy" ).withLocale( locale );

LocalDate localDate1 = formatterShort.parse( input1, LocalDate :: from );
// LocalDate localDate2 = formatter.parse( input2, LocalDate :: from );  // Fails… Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '24 Μαΐ 1967' could not be parsed at index 3.
LocalDate localDate3 = formatterFull.parse( input3, LocalDate :: from );

System.out.println( "localDate1 = " + localDate1 );
System.out.println( "localDate3 = " + localDate3 );
```

Comment: Mhh, thats a bit strange ... :D. You mentioned the different *"Μαΐ"*, but instead of fixing it you rather use `input1` for both `LocalDate` instances. Copy and paste mistake?

Comment: @Tom Yes, that was a mistake. Thanks for catching that. When I fixed that mistake I discovered the second spelling "Μαΐ" fails parsing.

Comment: Yes, the second one is kind of strange. Maybe a different letter in the greek alphabet.

Comment: Not that I know any greek at all but this might be from the long name of the month. It is written ```Μαΐου``` so there's a ```ΐ``` character in there.

Comment: @FranzBecker Yes, you seem to have found the solution. That second input string may be a bad abbreviation. Using the full month name you provided does indeed parse successfully. See my edit to the Answer with demo code.

Answer (score 6):

This works on my machine (Java 8):

```
String dateString = "24 Μαϊ 1967"; // just an example of an input String
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", new Locale("el", "GR"));
format.parse(dateString);
```

You can print out the available short months like this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("el", "GR");
DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale);
for (String m : dfs.getShortMonths()) {
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine here (on Java 8) if

- you pass the greek locale to the SimpleDateFormat constructor: `Locale.forLanguageTag("el")`
- you use `Μαϊ` and not `Μαΐ`.

  ```
  String dateString = "24 Μαϊ 1967"; // just an example of an input String
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.forLanguageTag("el"));
  Date parsed = format.parse(dateString);
  System.out.println("parsed = " + parsed); // parsed = Wed May 24 00:00:00 CET 1967
  ```

Comment: `Locale.forLanguageTag("el")` would also work (just a note :)).

Comment: FYI, I believe Tom's comment refers to the fact that [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) was revamped in Java 7 and Java 8 with new static methods for getting `Locale` instances. The old-school constructors remain in place for compatibility (not deprecated).

Comment: I didn't know this factory method (I usually use one of the constants). The post has been edited. Thanks to both of you.